# C#: If condition in Linq where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I've a Linq query like this...

```
var path = paths.Where(p=>input_path.ToUpper().Contains(p.ToUpper()).Select(p);
```

I've `C:\volume1` and `C:\volume10` in `paths` variable. Possible values for `input_path` are

```
"C:\volume1"
"C:\volume1\myFolder\myfile.txt"
"C:\volume10"
"C:\volume10\myFolder\myfile.txt"
```

If `input_path` is set to `C:\volume10\myFolder\myfile.txt`, by the above query it returns me `C:\volume1` where I'm expecting `C:\volume10`. I'd like to have a check something like the below

```
var path = paths.Where(p=>input_path.ToUpper().Contains(p.ToUpper()) && (if input_path.length > p.length then if input_path[p.length] == '\\') ).Select(p);
```

How do I do it using Linq? The "\" character check should happen only if `input_path` length is more than `path` length.

Edit:
"Paths" contain only the drive letter and first level directory, where as "input_path" can contain multilevel directories.

Comment: remove `if`'s and change `then` to &&

Comment: If you are searching for an exact match why do you use Contains? Use simply ==

Comment: I'm wondering if that will work if both "Paths" and "input_path" contain "C:\volume10". Length is same here.

Comment: @Steve Not `==`, since it's still a partial match, but it could be improved by using `StartsWith`.

Comment: @Steve, it is not exact match. Paths only contain the first level directory. I'll edit the post.

Comment: And as unrelated asides, there are several practices here that are often bad ideas leading to bugs. The first is doing string matching using `ToUpper`/`ToLower` when using a `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` would be better. And the second is parsing paths manually, when you could be using classes like `System.IO.Directory` or `System.Uri` to get more control over path segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
var path = paths.Where(p => input_path.ToUpper().Contains(p.ToUpper()) 
           && (input_path.Length > p.Length  && input_path[p.Length] == '\\'));
```

It will check input_path[p.Length] == '\' condition only if input_path.Length > p.Length is true.

Answer (score 4):

A lambda inside a LINQ method can have two syntaxes - either an [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173144.aspx) or a [statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx).

An expression is something that evaluates to a value. It's what you can have on the right-hand side of an assignment, for instance, and by default, it's what you have in a lambda. If you want to have a complex expression, you can use logical operators like && or || or the ?: ternary to group conditions together into a compound logic expression which evaluates to True or False.

```
paths.Where (p => input_path.Contains(p) 
           && (input_path.Length > p.Length && input_path[p.length] == '\\'))
```

Alternately, you can use a *lambda statement* by simply encasing the code in a set of {}, and then you can write a whole statement block, using `return` to return a value:

```
paths.Where(p => 
    { 
        if (input_path.Contains(p))
           if (input_path.length > p)
              if (input_path[p.length] = '\\')
              {
                  return true;
              }
        return false;
    }
```

Although in your case, the statement syntax is pretty contrived, and the first seems simplest.

Answer (score 2):

if you need just paths on subfolders of input_path, you can simply check if the path starts with your input path (adding the "\" at the end if necessary)

```
input_path = input_path.EndsWith('\\') ? input_path : input_path + '\\';
var path = paths.Where(p=> p.ToUpper().StartsWith(input_path.ToUpper())).Select(p);
         `
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you

```
var path = paths.Where(p => input_path.ToUpper().Contains(p.ToUpper()) && (input_path.length > p.length && input_path[p.length] == '\\'))
                .Select(p => p);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a couple of things:

1. It's slightly faster code (and less typing) to get rid of the `Where` and just use `Select`
2. If you're always comparing the start of the string, use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains` (and `ToUpper`). `StartsWith` takes a comparer, so you can specify that it ignores case

.

```
// Rules: 
// if input_path is longer than path, then see if it begins with path 
// (case-insensitive) and check for the backslash character
// otherwise, the two strings should be equal (case-insensitive)
var path = paths.Select(p =>
    (input_path.Length > p.Length &&
        input_path.StartsWith(p, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
        input_path[p.Length] == '\\') ||
    input_path.Equals(p, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```